# Product Images back end disappeared

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, magento1.9.3.1

I'm having a problem with product images. The website built on magento version 1.9.3.1; in Back end, manage product-product-images, I do not see the uploaded images for the product.

also attach a picture to understand the problem.

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Whats mean notification on yellow back? You can check You have set 777 on media folder

Comment: Hi konrad, the yellow notification mean: Image type and information need to be specified for each store view.
I checked permision media folder and subfolder, they are 755.

Comment: I see there are missing checkbox for remove and exclude. Please check Firebug errors in console.

Comment: You are missing some jss probably? Try clear js/css. Have you it merged?

Comment: I check and there areerrors: (index):1575 Uncaught ReferenceError: media_gallery_contentJsObject is not defined(…)onmouseover @

Comment: have you change something in layout / js files? Have you tried clear caches? 
Check also var/log/system.log and va/log/exceptions.log

Comment: No, I haven't change layout. I have update two time the site. The first from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.30, and second time to 1.9.3.1.

Comment: I solved it, the problem is CreareSeo extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem, in my case, is CreareSeo extension.
I update it to 1.5 versione and all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I use Firefox. Using the lastest version of Google Chrome solved the problem for me.

Comment: I tryed with Chrome, edge, firefox and opera browser... all same, the imags not shows.

Answer (score 0):

Try activer css and javascript in system->configuration->developer->settings